# replaceWithHyponym function selects a word from the text and replaces it with a hyponym, resulting in index out of range

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

```
self.lines.append([random.randint(10,700),random.randint(10,950), \
                   "Once there was a dog and a cat","l0"])
self.lines.append([random.randint(10,700),random.randint(10,950), \
                   "Who decided to have an extended natter","l1"])
```

This is the text analyzed.

```
def replaceWithHyponym(lines):
        ll = lines.pop(random.randrange(len(lines)))
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(ll[2])
        wordIdx = random.randrange(len(tokens))
        wordToBeReplaced = tokens[wordIdx]

        print('wordToBeReplaced')
        print(wordToBeReplaced)
        
        vehicle = wordnet.synsets(wordToBeReplaced)[0]
        typeofword = wordnet.synsets(vehicle.name())
        typesOfhyponyms = list(set([w for s in vehicle.closure(lambda s: s.hyponyms()) for w in s.lemma_names()]))
        print('typesOfhyponyms')            
        print(typesOfhyponyms)

        if typesOfhyponyms:
            tokens[wordIdx] = random.choice(typesOfhyponyms)
        else:
            tokens[wordIdx] = wordToBeReplaced
        print('tokens')
        print(tokens)

        newLine = " ".join(tokens)
        lines.append([ll[0],ll[1],newLine,ll[3]])
        return lines
```

This function runs continously until the text is poetic enough.

```
Error:

*** in run

[[325, 130, 'Once there was a dog and a cat', 'l0'], [684, 268, 'Who decided to have an extended natter', 'l1']]

2

executing  <function replaceWithHypernym at 0x000001BFA0142708>

wordToBeReplaced:

a

typesOfhyponyms:

[]

tokens:

['Once', 'there', 'was', 'a', 'dog', 'and', 'a', 'cat']

*** in run

[[684, 268, 'Who decided to have an extended natter', 'l1'], [325, 130, 'Once there was a dog and a cat', 'l0']]

2
executing  <function replaceWithHypernym at 0x000001BFA0142708>

wordToBeReplaced:

decided

typesOfhyponyms:

['calliper', 'adjudicate', 'reverse', 'stick', 'vote', 'pick_out', 'dedicate', 'define', 'overthrow', 'cream_off', 'turn_thumbs_down', 'put_up', 'regularise', 'anoint', 'calibrate', 'sieve', 'standardise', 'standardize', 'override', 'will', 'redefine', 'orientate', 'shoot', 'determine', 'measure_out', 'sieve_out', 'mensurate', 'pick_over', 'take_out', 'empanel', 'propose', 'judge', 'panel', 'quantify', 'set', 'cull_out', 'field', 'vote_in', 'reset', 'overturn', 'sift', 'orient', 'choose', 'poll', 'guide_on', 'screen_out', 'order', 'adopt', 'ballot', 'reelect', 'excerpt', 'overrule', 'rule_in', 'rule', 'outvote', 'decree', 'espouse', 'winnow', 'set_apart', 'co-opt', 'select', 'regularize', 'vote_down', 'resolve', 'limit', 'regulate', 'govern', 'impanel', 'skim_off', 'assign', 'think_of', 'hand-pick', 'pick', 'rule_out', 'seal', 'return', 'adhere', 'measure', 'detail', 'gauge', 'elect', 'screen', 'name', 'caliper', 'guide', 'purpose', 'draw', 'reorientate', 'put_forward', 'fix', 'take', 'extract', 'triangulate', 'dial', 'follow', 'specify', 'reorient', 'court-martial', 'plump', 'single_out', 'nominate', 'zone', 'try', 'district', 'sort', 'write_in', 'go']

tokens:

['Who', 'overthrow', 'to', 'have', 'an', 'extended', 'natter']

*** in run

[[325, 130, 'Once there was a dog and a cat', 'l0'], [684, 268, 'Who overthrow to have an extended natter', 'l1']]

2

executing  <function replaceWithHypernym at 0x000001BFA0142708>

wordToBeReplaced:

a

typesOfhyponyms:

[]

tokens:

['Once', 'there', 'was', 'a', 'dog', 'and', 'a', 'cat']

*** in run

[[684, 268, 'Who overthrow to have an extended natter', 'l1'], [325, 130, 'Once there was a dog and a cat', 'l0']]

2

executing  <function replaceWithHypernym at 0x000001BFA0142708>

wordToBeReplaced:

a

typesOfhyponyms:

[]

tokens:

['Once', 'there', 'was', 'a', 'dog', 'and', 'a', 'cat']

*** in run

[[684, 268, 'Who overthrow to have an extended natter', 'l1'], [325, 130, 'Once there was a dog and a cat', 'l0']]

2

executing  <function replaceWithHypernym at 0x000001BFA0142708>

wordToBeReplaced:

there

typesOfhyponyms:

[]

tokens:
['Once', 'there', 'was', 'a', 'dog', 'and', 'a', 'cat']

*** in run

[[684, 268, 'Who overthrow to have an extended natter', 'l1'], [325, 130, 'Once there was a dog 
and a cat', 'l0']]

2

executing  <function replaceWithHypernym at 0x000001BFA0142708>

wordToBeReplaced:

extended

typesOfhyponyms:

['territorialise', 'stretch', 'territorialize', 'globalize', 'globalise', 'broaden']

tokens:

['Who', 'overthrow', 'to', 'have', 'an', 'broaden', 'natter']

*** in run

[[325, 130, 'Once there was a dog and a cat', 'l0'], [684, 268, 'Who overthrow to have an broaden natter', 'l1']]

2

executing  <function replaceWithHypernym at 0x000001BFA0142708>

wordToBeReplaced:

to

***Exception in Tkinter callback***

***Traceback (most recent call last):***

  ***File "C:\Users\essam\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__***
    ***return self.func(*args)***

  ***File "C:\Users\essam\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 749, in callit***
    ***func(*args)***

  ***File "<ipython-input-145-8131f290a692>", line 25, in run***
   ***self.lines = ag(self.lines)***

  ***File "<ipython-input-145-8131f290a692>", line 45, in replaceWithHypernym***
    ***vehicle = wordnet.synsets(wordToBeReplaced)[0]***

***IndexError: list index out of range***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from `vehicle = wordnet.synsets("to")[0]` (if I've understood the debug output correctly).

The error says `[0]` is out of range, which must mean `wordnet.synsets("to")` has returned an empty list. I.e. "to" is not found in any synsets.

So you need to assign `wordnet.synsets(wordToBeReplaced)` to a variable, and check the list length is at least 1 (and return early if it is zero?) before getting `[0]`.

(If you return early when no synsets are found, just be aware of the potential for infinite loops. I'd be inclined to return false, or throw an exception, to indicate that no words were changed.)

Comment: executing  <function replaceWithHyponyms at 0x00000179CBBAD168>

wordToBeReplaced:

to

Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\essam\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\essam\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)

  File "<ipython-input-23-756d5d353aa6>", line 36, in run

    for ll in self.lines:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable 

THIS IS THE ERROR I GET NOW

Comment: @EssamAlKomey Unless you think this is all part of the same problem, you should start a new question on StackOverflow (and accept this answer if it helped answer the original question).   (Also try googling your error message, and make sure you've read up on how python for-in loops work... it sounds like you've accidentally assigned an int to `self.lines`)